# Julia symbolic differentiation

Tags: julia, symbolic-math, calculus, differentiation

Though I've looked through several pages documenting various differentiation tools in Julia, I have yet to find the following simple functionality. I want to define a function which is differentiable by hand, e.g, `f(x) = 2x.^3`, then call a symbolic computation function to obtain `fprime = derivative(f)`. This code should produce the same results as `fprime(x) = 6x.^2`. Is there a library function which acts like the made-up function `derivative` above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various packages for [automatic differentiation (AD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) in Julia.  For a single-variable function like the one you describe, the simplest and fastest is probably the [ForwardDiff package](https://github.com/JuliaDiff/ForwardDiff.jl), which lets you do:

```
using ForwardDiff
fprime(x) = ForwardDiff.derivative(f, x)
```

ForwardDiff and other AD packages indeed compute the exact analytical derivative, equivalent to the `6x^2` you might write by hand.  (However, the algorithms are a bit different from the "form a big symbolic expression then differentiate" that you might imagine.)

Comment: This is nice, but does not work if I try to broadcast vectors through ```fprime```. I suppose I'm really looking for a result equivalent to ```6x.^2```.

Comment: Broadcasting works just fine, e.g. `fprime.([1,2,3])` returns `[6, 24, 54]`.

Comment: Oops, I see that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `Symbolics.jl` package is capable of what you're looking for, although you need to explicitly declare what your variables are

```
In [2]: using Symbolics

In [3]: @variables x
Out[3]: 1-element Vector{Num}:
 x

In [4]: D = Differential(x)
Out[4]: (::Differential) (generic function with 2 methods)

In [5]: f(t) = 2*t^3
Out[5]: f (generic function with 1 method)

In [6]: expand_derivatives(D(f(x)))
Out[6]: 6(x^2)
```

You can read more about it here: https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/dev/manual/derivatives/

Answer (score 1):

If you work numerically with symbolic derivatives you can also use code-to-code symbolic differentiation by `using Zygote`

Assume you have `f(x) = 2x^3` than having Zygote loaded you can do

```
julia> f'(5)
150.0
```

to understand what just happened peek into the compilation process to see that the function `f` has been actually symbolically differentiated.

```
julia> @code_llvm f'(5)
define double @"julia_#79_991"(i64 signext %0) #0 {
  top:
       %1 = mul i64 %0, 3
       %2 = mul i64 %1, %0
       %3 = sitofp i64 %2 to double
       %4 = fmul double %3, 2.000000e+00
  ret double %4
}
```

Comment: Very slick, but I'm interested in a persistent function which implements the derivative. Could I, for instance, minimize ```f``` by calling a root-finding routine on ```f'```?

Comment: Depends on what you exactly need to do but for an example here people use it with Optim.jl: https://docs.juliahub.com/DeconvOptim/I6Omf/0.1.1/workflow/basic_workflow/